# Will string.GetHashCode() return negative value?

Tags: c#, string, hash, gethashcode

I tried with batch of random strings, all values I got are positive, but I wondering:

Will  `String.GetHashCode()` return negative or 0?

Since the return value is **int**, so I guess it might be, so if it is the case, I have to change my logic.

If you have answer or have some official sources, please share

Comment: FYI, GetHashCode is part of .NET, not part of C#

Comment: Looking at the logic via Reflector, I would say so.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2005/10/24/do-not-use-string-hashes-for-security-purposes.aspx

Comment: http://vkreynin.wordpress.com/2008/07/05/explaining-gethashcode-method/ check this :)

Comment: You probably would have seen negative results when sampling string of (strongly) varying lengths.

Comment: You chose an atypical batch of "random" strings then.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, it can return negative values.

You **must not** have any logic that works with `GetHashCode()` values.
`GetHashCode()` is not guaranteed to be unique and can change between builds.

`GetHashCode()` must be treated as an opaque token that can be combined with other hashes or modded out into hashtables.

Comment: SLaks is right - particularly between 32-bit and 64-bit architectures.

Comment: wow, it changes between builds, that sucks, I have to use something else, thanks anyway :)

Comment: Yes; you _must_ use something else.  `GetHashCode()` is only for in-memory hashtables.  You should probably use SHA512.

Comment: @Barlow, so if I constant build on x64, the value won't change, right? How about x128, eventually we will have

Comment: @EricYin: **DO NOT DO THIS**! See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2005/10/24/do-not-use-string-hashes-for-security-purposes.aspx

Comment: @Slaks, sure, I will stick to my SHA512, its very easy and fast in .NET anyway

Comment: @SLaks what if I just want to have a seed for my Random generator. I just cannot use Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode(); ?

Comment: @Teomanshipahi: If you don't care about security or predictability, anything is fine.  If this is at all related to crypto, you must use a secure PRNG.

Comment: Updated working URL to Eric Lippert's blog post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2005/10/24/do-not-use-string-hashes-for-security-purposes/

Answer (score 7):

It can return negative value (based on msdn):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode.aspx